# Tailwind using the top of an image for a circle profile pic

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an image

231x419

this size won't change, but the scale might.

I want to display a smaller profile image but only filling the circle with a part of the top of the image.

[image]

Basically just showing the circle part in the image above.

This circle area will be shown on a header.

Not sure what the best way to go about this, where the full image does not distort the header height etc.

My current circle image is:

```
       <a href="#" className="block relative">
          <img
            alt="name"
            src="/images/1.jpg"
            className="h-10 mx-auto object-cover rounded-full w-10"
          />
        </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't think this is quite what you wanted as I am not sure how it would handle different sizes. I can delete the answer or leave it here if it will help anyone.**

I gave it a go using `object-none` and then a custom class that sets the `object-position`.

See how this looks,
https://play.tailwindcss.com/XnHzOUO2IO

```html
<a href="#" className="block relative">
  <img 
    alt="name" 
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgkK0.png" 
    className="object-none w-36 h-36 rounded-full custom-position" />
</a>
```

```css
.custom-position {
  object-position: 60% -3px;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but I now need to make it sightly more complex. I created a new question to not add extra on this, check it out if you think you might have some more insight!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72624280/tailwind-showing-a-circular-profile-version-of-a-component-that-contains-images

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @stickyuser's answer, you can avoid having custom class by using `object-[59%_-4px]` class.

Tailwind playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/olB8hotsAX

```html
<a href="#" className="block relative">
  <img alt="name" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgkK0.png" class="h-36 w-36 rounded-full object-none object-[59%_-4px]" />
</a>
```

[image]

It can be also done with background position:

```html
<a href="#" className="block relative">
  <div class="h-36 w-36 rounded-full bg-[59%_-4px]" style="background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgkK0.png)"></div>
</a>
```